# 1D CNN for classification

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, classification, conv-neural-network

I am building a convolutional neural network (with Tensorflow) that should classify one-dimensional inputs.

Here is my code so far:

```
import tensorflow as tf

n_outputs = 1
batch_size = 32
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [batch_size, 10, 1])

filt = tf.zeros([3, 1, 1])

output = tf.nn.conv1d(x, filt, stride=2, padding="VALID")

y = tf.placeholder(tf.int32)
logits = tf.layers.dense(output, n_outputs)
xentropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y, logits=logits)
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
```

When I run the code above, I get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>         File "minex.py", line 16, in 
>           correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(logits, y, 1)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_nn_ops.py",
>   line 1449, in in_top_k
>           targets=targets, k=k, name=name)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py",
>   line 763, in apply_op
>           op_def=op_def)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 2329, in create_op
>           set_shapes_for_outputs(ret)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1717, in set_shapes_for_outputs
>           shapes = shape_func(op)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py",
>   line 1667, in call_with_requiring
>           return call_cpp_shape_fn(op, require_shape_fn=True)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py",
>   line 610, in call_cpp_shape_fn
>           debug_python_shape_fn, require_shape_fn)
>         File "/home/jk/tensorflow/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/common_shapes.py",
>   line 676, in _call_cpp_shape_fn_impl
>           raise ValueError(err.message)
>       ValueError: Shape must be rank 2 but is rank 3 for 'InTopK' (op: 'InTopK') with input shapes: [32,4,1], ?.

Based on the error, it seems that my problem is with the shapes, but I am not sure why is it happening or how to correct it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [tf.squeeze](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/squeeze) to remove the outer dimension from your logits.

Your last line could become:

```
correct = tf.nn.in_top_k(tf.squeeze(logits), y, 1)
```

That will bring the shape of the logits tensor from [32, 4, 1] to [32, 4].

Comment: Some other resources might mention [tf.reshape](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/reshape) which is a more generic solution but in this case tf.squeeze is more simple to understand. Next to this [tf.expand_dims](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/expand_dims) which does more or less the inverse than tf.squeeze.